# How to bring some difinite items (symbols) based on the chosen item

Tags: excel

I am wondering if it is possible when I choose some item from let's say drop down menu in one place , on some other place to appear just some definite items that are preliminary identified to be related to this item. As an example, if you have a company structure- See below the picture- Subsidiary 1( Sub1) has just one Subsidiary with a code Sub1Sub1, so I will be expecting under the required place to appear (which might be in different worksheet )  just Su1Sub1, if I choose Sub2 from the main menu, I will be expecting in this place to get  Sub1Sub2 and Sub2 (two different rows) , etc. Initially I was thinking to do this with multiple vlookup formula with syntaxis (iferror(index(.....),small(..)), but in this case we don't have values to bring, we have a combination of symbols  (Sub1sub2) etc.. It can be done with multiple if(if(if( etc, but imagine we have  many companies so it would be difficult with if(if)s..Please advise.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list box element to select from your master entities.
Use the Change event of this list box to preload a second listbox for the child entities via VBA

The same can be done with the data validation items if you prefer in cell dropdowns. Then you use the worksheet_change event and check if the cell containing the master entity has changed, and if so you reload the correct set of child entities into the data validation list of the child selection field.